# Understanding Example 4.1.2 in Fulton's Intersection Theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, intersection-theory

The following appears in Fulton's *Intersection Theory*, and I'm not sure how to prove it.

> **Example 4.1.2**
> Assume $C$ is a purely $n$-dimensional cone, and $P(C_i)$ is not empty for each irreducible component $C_i$ of $C$. Then
> $$s(C) = \sum_{i \geq 0} p_* \left(c_1(\mathcal O(1))^i \cap [P(C)] \right),$$
> where $p: P(C) \to X$ is the projection. (Use Lemma 1.7.2 with Proposition 4.1 (b); by Appendix B.5.2, $c_1(\mathcal O(1)) \cap P(C \oplus 1) = P(C)$.)

Lemma 1.7.2 and Propositioin 4.1 (b) both are  concerned  with decomposition into irreducible components, especially we need the assumption that $C$ is equidimensional, to apply Lemma 1.7.2. However, I don't even know where to apply those. Here is what I tried, which imo looks promising:

Let $i: P(C) \hookrightarrow P(C \oplus 1)$ be the inclusion, and $q: P(C  \oplus 1) \to X$ be the second projection.
By definition of the Segre class, we have
\begin{align*}
s(C) & = q_* \left( \sum_{i \geq 0} c_1(\mathcal O_{P(C \oplus 1)}(1))^i \cap [P(C \oplus 1)]\right) \\
& = q_* [P(C \oplus 1)] + q_* \left(\sum_{i \geq 1} c_1(\mathcal O_{P(C \oplus 1)}(1))^i \cap [P(C \oplus 1)]\right)
\end{align*}
Applying the second part of the hint to  the sum we get
\begin{align*}
s(C) &= q_* [P(C \oplus 1)] + \sum_{i \geq 1} q_* \left( c_1(\mathcal O_{P(C \oplus 1)}(1))^{i-1} \cap i_*[P(C)] \right) \\
& \stackrel{\rho}{=} q_* [P(C \oplus 1)] +  \sum_{i \geq 1} q_* i_* \left(c_1(\mathcal O_{P(C)}(1))^{i-1} \cap [P(C)]\right) \\
& = q_* [P(C \oplus 1)] + \sum_{i \geq 0} p_* \left(c_1(\mathcal O_{P(C)}(1))^{i} \cap [P(C)]\right),
\end{align*}
where $\rho$ is an application of the projection formula. So it remains to show
$$q_* [P(C \oplus 1)] = 0.$$
Now the irreducible components of $P(C \oplus 1)$ are the $P(C_i \oplus 1)$, which have relative dimension $\geq 1$ over $X$, since each $P(C_i)$ is non-empty by assumption. This implies $q_* [P(C_i \oplus 1)] = 0$, by the definition of the push-forward of cycles, and we are done.

I'm confused because I did not use Lemma 1.7.2 and Proposition 4.1 (b), and so I didn't need the assumption that $C$ is equidimensional. Did I make a mistake?

Additional question: Is there a counterexample when $C$ is not equidimensional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you do not need Proposition 4.1 (b), but you need Lemma 1.7.2 to deduce
$$c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))\cap[P(C\oplus 1)]=[P(C)].$$
Let $W_1,\dots,W_n$ be the irreducible components of $P(C\oplus 1)$ and $m_i$ be the multiplicity of $W_i$.
Let $D$ denote the effective Cartier divisor $P(C)$ on $P(C\oplus 1)$.
The associated line bundle $\mathcal{O}(D)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(1)$, so we have
$$
c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))\cap[P(C\oplus 1)]= \sum_im_i[D|_{W_i}]
$$
by the definition of $c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))\cap({-})$.
Therefore it remains to prove
$$
\sum_i m_i[D|_{W_i}]=[D],
$$
which is nothing but Lemma 1.7.2.